# Pickling lists with their names from Notebook and Unpickling them in Notebook2

Tags: python, jupyter, pickle

I have three lists in variables in a jupyter Notebook (Notebook1).

```
conso_emi = ['ENERGYSTARScore', 'SiteEUI(kBtu/sf)', 'SiteEUIWN(kBtu/sf)']
surf = ['PropertyGFAParking', 'LargestPropertyUseTypeGFA']
num_caract = ['NumberofBuildings', 'NumberofFloors', 'Age']
```

I want to reuse these variables and their list in another notebook (Notebook2). To do so:

TRY 1: I used a pickler in Notebook1 to save them as a list of lists:
In Notebook1:

```
list_lists = [conso_emi,
            surf,
            num_caract,]

with open("Documents/OC/P4/var_funcs", 'wb') as fic:
    mon_pickler = pickle.Pickler(fic)
    mon_pickler.dump(list_lists)
```

In Notebook2:

```
with open("Documents/OC/P4/var_funcs", 'rb') as fic:
    mon_depickler = pickle.Unpickler(fic)
    loaded = mon_depickler.load()
loaded
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['ENERGYSTARScore', 'SiteEUI(kBtu/sf)', 'SiteEUIWN(kBtu/sf)'],
 ['PropertyGFAParking', 'LargestPropertyUseTypeGFA'],
 ['NumberofBuildings', 'NumberofFloors', 'Age']]
```

This works, but I am loosing the names of of the lists I had in Notebook1: conso_emi, surf, num_caracts

TRY 2: Instead of saving a list of lists, I have saved the three lists as a dict where the key is the list (variable) name, and the value the list itself In Notebook1:

```
dic_lists = {'conso_emi':conso_emi,
            'surf':surf,
            'num_caract':num_caract}

with open("Documents/OC/P4/var_funcs", 'wb') as fic:
    mon_pickler = pickle.Pickler(fic)
    mon_pickler.dump(dic_lists)
```

In Notebook2:

```
with open("C:/Users/VP/Documents/OC/P4/var_funcs", 'rb') as fic:
    mon_depickler = pickle.Unpickler(fic)
    loaded = mon_depickler.load()
loaded
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'conso_emi':['ENERGYSTARScore', 'SiteEUI(kBtu/sf)', 'SiteEUIWN(kBtu/sf)'],
 'surf':['PropertyGFAParking', 'LargestPropertyUseTypeGFA'],
 'num_caract':['NumberofBuildings', 'NumberofFloors', 'Age']}
```

I was then thinking to recreate the variables from the keys and the values, but I was explained in a previous post and other posts suggested that it is not a good practice.
Is there any proper and fast way of reusing or recreating these three lists and their names in Notebook2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first one and do `conso_emi, surf, num_caract = loaded` in the second notebook.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, is there any way to reuse the names from a notebook to another without having to write them ? Let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: I'd say not without bad hacks. And you're writing them in the second notebook anyway, when you're *using* them.

Comment: Could you explain what bad hack mean please ? I am not sure I understand

Comment: Something like using `exec` or writing into `globals()`.

Comment: I gave a look into exec, but I think will go with the first solution you gave